# How to access Session from a custom data annotation in an ASP.NET MVC project?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, session, authentication, data-annotations

For some experimental/exercise purposes, I'm trying to implement a primitive login system before proceeding to Identity services.

My idea was creating a custom data annotation -just like [Authorize] of Identity- and passing inputted form data carried by Session[]. Hence, I would use my custom annotation to authorize certain controllers or methods.

```
public class IdCheck: ValidationAttribute
    {
        public string currentId { get; set; }

        public override bool IsValid(object value)
        {
            currentId = value as string;
            if (currentId != null)
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
```

and I tried to use it like that:

```
[IdCheck(currentId = Session["UserId"])]
public class SomeController : Controller
{
//methods
}
```

However, I got an error with the message: "An object reference is required for the non static field, method or property 'Controller.Session'"

I can neither access the Session[] before a controller nor before method declaration. I have no idea how to instantiate or refere.

Is there a way to utilize Session[] in my case? Because I don't want to manually check each method with if statements like

```
if(Session["UserId"] != null) {}
```

Any alternative solution is more than welcomed.

Note: I am aware of that using Session is not a recommended way of implementing such a task. But my intention is to have an understanding of how login operations work before utilizing advanced Identity services.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is there a way to utilize Session[] in my case?

Not as you're doing now, but you could use HttpContext.Current.Session inside your custom attribute code instead of passing it as property.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot Oscar. What you proposed actually worked. However, I managed to find a better way yo carry out my "primitive login" operation using a custom data annotation.

After some more research it turned out that implementing FilterAttribute class along with IAuthorizationFilter filter does the trick. I believe this could help someone else as well:

```
public class IdCheck : FilterAttribute, IAuthorizationFilter
    {
        public void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
        {
            if (filterContext.HttpContext.Session["UserId"] == null)
            {
                filterContext.Result = new RedirectResult("/");
            }
        }
    }
```

and the usage is the same of course:

```
[IdCheck]
public class SomeController : Controller
{
//methods
}
```